# Visual Studio Solution Explorer doesn't find everything

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to find all the files in the solution that include some word. I used to just run search in the commander (Unreal Commander to be specific), but it would be convenient sometimes to do that without leaving IDE.

But solution explorer doesn't find every entry:
[image]

Even though "find references" does find it:

[image]

Is there a way to list all the files that have a specific word from inside Visual Studio and quickly cycle through it? It would make perfect sense to see that feature in Solution Explorer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>arrows</kbd>), but for some reason it doesn't find everything.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3

Comment: Have your tried Edit->Find and Replace->Find in Files?

Comment: Check out my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and then choose entire solution then find all.

A list of files that contains this word will appear in a Window.

Comment: Interesting, it even lets you cycle through entries with the preview. Just what I wanted, thanks. I also found that **Ctrl+Shift+F** automatically sets scope to 'entire solution'

Comment: It's still weird though that the Solution Explorer doesn't find every entry.

Answer (score 0):

For me I found the search within file contents was unchecked. As soon as I checked this it worked again.

Just to the right of the x of the search bar, hit the drop down arrow and check "Search within file contents"

[image: Screen grab showing drop down with Search within file contents ticked]